# Error handling, creating time line, need help defining what aspects of the environment need tracking

Tags: programming-languages, exceptions, errors, tracking

For my final year project, I'm working on a script that will run your python program and provide a time line of events(so far working on assignments) and create a story of what happened(the changes in the variables). Based on what Exception is thrown, you can choose to use the library made available by me to help figure out what happened and how it happened. (Hopefully I explained this much better than I did on stack overflow)

My question to you, besides the variables, when an error occurs/exception you cant handle occurs, what would you look through in order to try and fix the problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: This sounds very interesting!

Comment: I dont know if I undestand correctly but, I like to see a feature that let me identify code lines that takes a lot of time to execute.

Comment: @eiefai this sounds like a sweet idea(but it's ambiguous what you mean by too long but I have an idea of how I would tackle that) and I'll put it on the "if I have time at the end" pile. This framework is mainly debugging and my topic is about one of its features. The feature is to try and eliminate as many errors as possible. It does this by showing the side effects of each assignment i.e. how variables change over time. My question is: what other information can I track over the course of program to give more information when the error occurs?

Answer (score 2):

**The Call Stack With Arguments**

This might be a little obvious, but a lot of my error logs just consist of functions announcing they're beginning with a listing of the args passed. As you're creating your "story," make it obvious every time a function is called and display the args passed to the function.

Comment: Maybe not all of the functions called but definitely the functions that manipulate the variables involved in the error/exception. Which is why I'm asking my question. For example, a function that manipulates a database. This is a de emphasis of variables and more on the state of tables and stuf in a database.

Comment: with db manipulation you can log any statements executed and results returned, but that may get lengthy.